# Install docker and docker-compose on Azure using cloud-Init

Tags: azure, cloud-init

I wanted to bootstrap my Azure VM with Docker and Docker-compose using cloud-init. So far I tried something like below.

```
#cloud-config

package_update: true
package_upgrade: true

groups:
  - docker: [default]

runcmd:
  - [ sh, -c, "curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh" ]
  - [ sh, -c, "sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$(git ls-remote https://github.com/docker/compose | grep refs/tags | grep -oP "[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]+\.[0-9]+$" | tail -n 1)/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose" ]
  - [ sh, -c, "sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose" ]
```

But it doesn't install the docker/ docker-compose and get below error

```
cloud-init[958]: 2019-02-28 00:51:02,447 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed loading yaml blob. Invalid format at line 11 column 32: "while scanning a plain scalar
[  333.241244] cloud-init[958]:   in "<unicode string>", line 11, column 32:
[  333.245521] cloud-init[958]:         - [ sh, -c, "sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compos ...
2019/02/28 00:51:04.015216 INFO Daemon Wire protocol version:2012-11-30
[  333.245619] cloud-init[958]:                                    ^
[  333.259509] cloud-init[958]: found unexpected ':'
[  333.259584] 2019/02/28 00:51:04.019282 INFO Daemon Server preferred version:2015-04-05
cloud-init[958]:   in "<unicode string>", line 11, column 37:
[  333.474295] cloud-init[958]:         - [ sh, -c, "sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/rel ...
[  333.514672] cloud-init[958]:                                         ^
[  333.554215] cloud-init[958]: Please check http://pyyaml.org/wiki/YAMLColonInFlowContext for details."
[  333.593764] cloud-init[958]: 2019/02/28 00:51:04.361760 INFO Daemon Waiting for ssh host key be generated at /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub [1800 attempts remaining, sleeping 1s]
2019-02-28 00:51:02,470 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed loading yaml blob. Invalid format at line 11 column 32: "while scanning a plain scalar
[  333.705350] cloud-init[958]:   in "<unicode string>", line 11, column 32:
[  333.731074] cloud-init[958]:         - [ sh, -c, "sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compos ...
[  333.769118] cloud-init[958]:                                    ^
[  333.789992] cloud-init[958]: found unexpected ':'
[  333.808855] cloud-init[958]:   in "<unicode string>", line 11, column 37:
[  333.831502] cloud-init[958]:         - [ sh, -c, "sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/rel ...
[  333.863028] cloud-init[958]:                                         ^
[  333.885648] cloud-init[958]: Please check http://pyyaml.org/wiki/YAMLColonInFlowContext for details."
[  333.915174] cloud-init[958]: 2019-02-28 00:51:02,470 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed at merging in cloud config part from part-001
```

Apart from it I doubt how can I add Azure auto created default user (which was provided from UI) to docker group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time I solved it myself.

```
#cloud-config

package_update: true

# Setup swap memory
disk_setup:
    ephemeral0:
        table_type: mbr
        layout: [66, [33, 82]]
        overwrite: True
fs_setup:
    - device: ephemeral0.1
      filesystem: ext4
    - device: ephemeral0.2
      filesystem: swap
mounts:
    - ["ephemeral0.1", "/mnt"]
    - ["ephemeral0.2", "none", "swap", "sw", "0", "0"]

# Enable Docker's swap limit support
bootcmd:
    - [ sh, -c, 'sudo echo GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1" >> /etc/default/grub' ]
    - [ sh, -c, 'sudo update-grub' ]
    - [ cloud-init-per, once, mymkfs, mkfs, /dev/vdb ]

# Install docker and docker-compose
runcmd:
    - [ sh, -c, 'curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh' ]
    - [ sh, -c, 'sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest | grep "tag_name" | cut -d \" -f4)/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose' ]
    - [ sh, -c, 'sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose' ]

# Add default auto created user to docker group
system_info:
    default_user:
        groups: [docker]
```

Comment: Note with this setup is uses the [docker convenience script](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-convenience-script) which comes with a big warning **Using these scripts is not recommended for production environments**

Answer (score 3):

Just tested by myself on Azure using Ubuntu 18.04-LTS:

```
#cloud-config
package_upgrade: true

packages:
    - docker.io
    - docker-compose

# create the docker group
groups:
    - docker

# assign a VM's default user, which is mydefaultuser, to the docker group
users:
    - default
    - name: mydefaultuser
      groups: docker
```

`runcmd` can be left empty for this setup.

Answer (score 1):

you have `"` inside of other `"` which doesnt work without escaping. as for the user. I think default user created has id of 1000, you can just use that (probably test this hypothesis before).